# Reusing Puppet Defined Type Parameter in Other Defined Type

Tags: puppet

Lets say I want to define a set of resources that have dependencies on each other, and the dependent resources should reuse parameters from their ancestors. Something like this:

```
server { 'my_server':
  path => '/path/to/server/root',
  ...
}

server_module { 'my_module':
  server => Server['my_server'],
  ...
}
```

The `server_module` resource both depends on `my_server`, but also wants to reuse the configuration of it, in this case the path where the server is installed. `stdlib` has functions for doing this, specifically `getparam()`.

Is this the "puppet" way to handle this, or is there a better way to have this kind of dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard "puppet way" to do this.  If you can get it done using the stdlib and you're happy with it, then by all means do it that way.

Personally, if I have a couple defined resources that both need the same data I'll do one of the follow:

1) Have a manifest that creates both resources and passes the data both need via parameters.  The manifest will have access to all data both resources need, whether shared or not.

2) Have both defined resources look up the data they need in Hiera.

I've been leaning more towards #2 lately.

Dependency is only a matter of declaring it.  So your server_module resource would have a "require => Server['my_server']" parameter --- or the server resource would have a "before => Server_module['my_module']".

Comment: I also believe these are the ways to go. The `getparam()` solution should never be used, as it introduces parsing order dependencies.